# Jquery Validation on Tabbed form

Tags: jquery

I have a tabbed form with 6 fields. 3 fields are active on each tab when any tab is clicked and the fields in other tab gets style `display:none`. How to validate the fields with style `display:none` ?

Comment: Simply doing it ? They are not gone in any way. They are simply invisible. Maybe I'm getting you wrong, but I dont't understand whats the problem ? Post some code !

Comment: Can you please provide some code of you work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the validator to ignore nothing(hidden fields, display none fields).

`ignore:''` will do it.

```
    $("#formId").validate({
        ignore : '',
        rules : {
             ...
        },
        messages : {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for just to check whether the element is visible or not than,

```
        $(element).is(":visible") or 
        $(element).is(':hidden') or
        $(element).css('display') == 'none'
```

will return if the element is hidden or not

Comment: Is there any way to validate fields with style display: none??

Comment: you mean you want to select those who are having display:none css. Than use $("span:hidden") and ya you can look http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can declare then use the function:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hiddenByParent = function(a) { 
   return jQuery(a).is(':hidden') && jQuery(a).css('display') != 'none'; 
};
```

to get the fields within hidden tabs.